# Error migración en Django por cambio de modelo

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, migration

Tengo un campo de un modelo en Django que lo he cambiado y añadido unique=True, porque quiero que ahora todo lo introducido en ese campo sea diferente.
El problema es, que si tengo en la base de datos valores iguales en ese campo que están guardados de antiguamente, me salta un error en la migración.
Mi pregunta es si existe alguna forma de hacer una condición para eso en la migración o el modelo, y si existen valores de dicho campo iguales en la base de datos de antes, que los ignore o que guarde el primero y ponga los otros a NULL.
Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: La migración depende completamente de tu base de datos, y dependiendo del tipo se puede hacer de una forma u otra. Aquí puedes encontrar más información: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/
Si tu base de datos es MySQL, entonces tienes que actualizar, según el criterio que decidas, los campos manualmente. 
No se puede hacer "que los ignore", pero sí que guarde el primero y ponga los otros a NULL, con un par de queries en SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Tendrias que crear primero una funcion que valide los datos, o en todo caso un sql que actualice porque sino al querer migrar salta la validacion y te generar error. 
Hazlo con sql seria mas rapido y limpio.